# DTD not determinist?

Tags: dtd

I have an xml document like this:

```
<root>
   <text>
       <ID>01</ID>
       <weight>1</weight>
       <word>attend</word>
       <note>important</note> 
   </text>  
   <text>
       <note>very important</note> 
       <ID>01</ID>
       <weight>1</weight>
       <word>slow</word>
   </text>
```

The rule is: Id, weight, word must appear in that order as the child of text node, And note node can appear before or after ID node. So My DTD is:

```
<!ELEMENT text (note?, ID, weight, word, note?)>
```

But xml editor says "this is not determinist". Why?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your DTD? That seems deterministic to me. Also, what editor are you using?

Comment: Yes, that line of DTD is deterministic. Also note that that line allows `<note>` to appear twice as a child element of `<text>`. You probably have a non-deterministic definition in some other line on your DTD.

Answer (score 0):

With this **`XML`** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "test.dtd">
<root>
    <text>
        <ID>01</ID>
        <weight>1</weight>
        <word>attend</word>
        <note>important</note> 
    </text>  
    <text>
        <note>very important</note> 
        <ID>01</ID>
        <weight>1</weight>
        <word>slow</word>
    </text>
</root>
```

and this **`DTD`** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT root (text+) >
<!ELEMENT text (note?, ID, weight, word, note?)>
<!ELEMENT note (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT ID (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT weight (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT word (#PCDATA) >
```

the document is valid, no errors (Oxygen Xml Editor 14.2)